# Cannot login in graphical mode - Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, login, nvidia-graphics-card

This is an old issue that I've tried to solve and apparently it's still valid, none of the updates so far have resolved it.
It seems to be related to Gnome (gdm?) and Nvidia drivers, because for ex. On my desktop PC I just sidestepped the issue with an LXDE based install, which works fine, however I really do like Gnome for some reason, so it would be great to find the cause/solution to this.

Here are the details:

After a fresh install and installing all updates (latest kernel for 10.04 and latest packages), I cannot login on the graphical login screen. After entering the password the screen will turn black for a few seconds and then returns back to the login screen. But if I go to terminal with ctrl+alt+f1 I can login just fine, so my username/password is definitely OK.

On my laptop I use Ubuntu 10.04 95% of the time, and never ran into this issue, so I suspect it's hardware related. Maybe something graphics related (I have an Nvidia 9800GT on my desktop, but Ati card on laptop).

Any ideas on what I should look for or try? Which logs should I check to find out possible reasons/solutions to this problem.

**Update**:

It is immediately after a fresh install, on first login, so I don't have restricted drivers enabled. Only nvidia related packages installed are `nvidia-173-modaliases`, `nvidia-96-modaliases`, `nvidia-common`, `nvidia-current-modaliases`.

If i boot into recovery mode as root, and then run `startx`, I can get into GNOME.

Output of `cat /var/log/gdm/:0-greeter.log`

```
Window manager warning: Failed to read saved session file /var/lib/gdm/.config/metacity/sessions/103537dbc1e1d90e94130703607828717100000014670000.ms: Failed to open file '/var/lib/gdm/.config/metacity/sessions/103537dbc1e1d90e94130703607828717100000014670000.ms': No such file or directory
** (process:1477): DEBUG: Greeter session pid=1477 display=:0.0 xauthority=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-Jf8At5/database

(gnome-power-manager:1478): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.24.1/gobject/gsignal.c:2273: signal `proxy-status' is invalid for instance `0x203ed90'
gdm-simple-greeter[1477]: Gtk-WARNING: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.20.1/gtk/gtkwidget.c:5636: widget not within a GtkWindow
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x1200047 (Login Wind)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x1200047 (Login Wind)
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
```

Comment: Did you install the proprietary Nvidia drivers, or are you using the built-in *Noveau* drivers?  If you log in on the text console and run `startx`, can you get into GNOME?

Comment: @Patches: Updated my question with more info.

Comment: @Beres:  Have you tried doing a full update?  (`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`)  If that doesn't help, please post the contents of `/var/log/gdm/:0-greeter.log`.

Comment: @Patches: Added the log output. So far I did `aptitude full-upgrade`, not `apt-get dist-upgrade` however, as I would've liked to use latest LTS distribution. But I'll try to upgrade the distribution too, I'm  curious if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @Patches: Please ignore my previous comment about `dist-upgrade`, my mistake. I do have all the packages up to date at the moment though.

Comment: @Beres:  The updates wouldn't have helped you anyway.  Your `greeter.log` output indicates that you're experiencing a bug that has not yet been fixed by Canonical.  I've posted an answer with two possible workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/539440) with the GNOME Display Manager (`gdm`) in Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx.

Comment #21 of that bug suggests disabling the Ubuntu logo splash screen will work around this issue.  To do so temporarily, you may edit the kernel arguments from the GRUB menu and remove the `splash` option.  To do so permanently, remove `splash` from the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` environment variable line in `/etc/default/grub`, and run `sudo update-grub` to make the changes take effect.

If that fails, you could also switch to a different display manager for the time being, like `lightdm` or KDE's `kdm` (which you can install without necessarily installing the KDE Plasma Desktop environment).  You won't get GNOME's login screen, but you will still be able to login to a GNOME desktop.  To install either of these, just run `sudo apt-get install lightdm` or `sudo apt-get install kdm` and restart.  To login to a GNOME session, just choose `GNOME` or `Ubuntu Desktop` from the *Session* menu of your chosen display manager.  It should remember your selection for future logins.

Comment: My father's machine had this problem but it was from an upgrade from 8.04 - `kdm` solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I didn't end up needing this however as the issue mysteriously disappeared after another reinstall and format of /home drive. Works fine even with restricted drivers enabled at the moment. On previous try I think I've missed formatting /home, however I did have other installs before that *with* reformatting, so that is not necessarily the obvious problem. Another difference is that I've set /home to be encrypted, but I'm not sure how that would "fix" this. If the issue suddenly reappears this workaround will certainly be the first thing I'll try.

Comment: Apparently the login issue only "went away" temporarily (on first boot after reinstall), after that it started behaving the same again. The `etc/default/grub` change didn't seem to help, but the workaround of installing `kdm` and then choosing GNOME session was OK.

Comment: @Beres:  If you haven't already, you can add `splash` back to `/etc/default/grub` and rerun `sudo update-grub` to get your pretty boot screen back.  Also, if you'd like, you can report your experience to that bug and subscribe to be notified when/if it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly an nvidia binary driver problem. Completely remove the binary nvidia driver (apt-get purge should do the trick; i forget the nvidia binary driver package - will a kind soul edit this answer?).

This should cause you to fall back to nouveau or vga. Nouveau will probably work but you will have some bugs and no 3D acceleration. (I had better luck w/ 10.10 and nouveau.)

VGA will certainly work but you'll be constrained to such a tiny screen size the only thing to do is install one of the other drivers.

Comment: It certainly seemed to be nvidia related, but I don't have the restricted drivers installed (fresh install, first login) so it looks like it's something else. Also removed all other nvidia related packages. Updated my question with more concrete info.